# Should I use Additional domain or Alias in OS-X Server

Tags: osx-server

I am setting up a Web server on a Mac Mini.

Let's assume that the website is at:   www.mydomain.com

I also wish the user to be able to access the website from:  mydomain.com

Should I be using an additional domain, or perhaps a domain alias? (from the set up screen in server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com should actually be the same web site, an alias would be the appropriate approach.

Alternatively, I prefer to setup mydomain.com as a separate website that is configured to be a redirect to www.mydomain.com. By doing so, the website can be reached both ways, but references (from users or search engines) will consistently be made to www.mydomain.com.